# What is a fair coin?

Tags: probability, philosophy

The title of this question is almost a retorical question. My point is that there is no way to define probability in a non circular manner.

Let's say the probality of getting a tail when tossing a coin is $\frac{1}{2}$, e.i the coin is fair. What does it mean? It means that the relative frequency of tails tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ as $N$ (the number of trials) tends to infinity. But what does the term "tends" means in this context? It means that the probability of getting any fixed relative frequency distinct from $\frac{1}{2}$ (say $\frac{1}{2}+0.0001$) tends to $0$ as $N$ tends to infinity. But we fall then in a circular definition!

Actually there is no way of knowing if the coin is fair, except by a physical exploration of the coin itself. (what, by quantum mechanics, won't really tell you with certainty if the coin is fair).

The only thing we can say, after tossing the coin a lot of times, is that the probability that the coin is fair enough is very high.

So my question is "What does it mean that the probablity of getting a tail is $\frac{1}{2}$?"

Comment: A fair coin is a mathematical concept and not a physical one. Therefore plain and simple: a fair coin is by definition a coin with equal probability of heads and tails.

Comment: So your question isn't really about what fair coin means, but rather what **probability** really means. Right?

Comment: You’re wrong that it’s impossible to define probability in a non-circular way; it’s just defined in terms of set theory, using a sample space of events, each of which is, by definition, associated with a probability between 0 and 1. However, like any mathematical model, it cannot perfectly mirror reality, which is what I think you’re trying to say - but that doesn’t *really* matter, since applications of these models have shown them to be practically useful.

Comment: Klaus, the mathematical concept of "fair coin" comes from a physical concept of a fair coin. People toss coins even without knowing anything about math, and they can have the concept of a fair coin. But mathematicians wouldn't use the mathematical concept if they didn't know about real coins in the world.

Comment: The rules of probability can be viewed as a system for *predicting* for what fraction of trials an event will occur if a random experiment is repeated a large number of times. The axiom that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint is a rule that your predictions must satisfy in order to be *consistent* with each other. There is of course no guarantee that your predictions will always be correct, or even close to correct, but if you need to make predictions then you may as well do so consistently and this requires using the rules of probability.

Comment: An alternative viewpoint is that probabilities represent subjective degrees of belief. You could check out Probability: The Logic of Science by Jaynes for one presentation of this viewpoint.

Comment: I have reedited the post, so as to clarify what the question is. ("What does it mean that the probability of getting a tail is 1/2?")

Comment: You're correct; there is no way to determine if a physical coin is fair.  There is also no way to determine if a physical rod is exactly one meter long.  Do you also claim there is no mathematical concept of length?

Comment: No, saulspatz, the concept of length is well defined but it is not a mathematical concept, Is a physical one, which in turn the mathematicians took to use in their own mathematical metric spaces. The length of a stick is a very different thing from the length of an element of a metric space (say a vector in an infinite dimension hilbert space). But both are well defined. In the case of probability, is the same thing. You can define mathematically what a probability is in terms of a measure but that doesn't say anything about the conection with the physical world.

Comment: On the other hand you can measure a stick and be sure for example that it is no larger than two meters nor shorter than one meter. But fliping a coin you can't be sure of anything at all about the fairness of  the coin. Even if you get 200 tails in a row you can't say the coin isn't fair (maybe you just have really bad luck)

Comment: "Probability has two aspects. There is a formal mathematical theory, axiomatized by Kolmogorov (1956). And there is an informal theory that
connects the mathematics to the world, i.e., defines what ‘probability’
means when applied to real events" from https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/Preprints/611.pdf